# Can we use CASE statement with INSERT on a big query table?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, subquery, inner-join, sql-insert

i am trying to append values corresponding to unique key values in main table from another sub table without a join.

Eg:

MAIN_TABLE:

```
COL1 | COL2 | COL3
aaa  | 1111 | a111 
bbb  | 2222 | b222 
ccc  | 3333 | c333 
ddd  | 4444 | d444 
abc  | 1233 | b222
```

SUB_TABLE

```
COL1 | COL2
Cat  | a111
Dog  | b222
bird | c333
fish | d444
```

I need the **RESULT** as below:

```
COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4
aaa  | 1111 | a111 | Cat 
bbb  | 2222 | b222 | Dog 
ccc  | 3333 | c333 | Bird
ddd  | 4444 | d444 | fish
abc  | 1233 | b222 | Dog
```

I was trying to achieve that by using CASE statement in an INSERT into Col 4 in BigQuery.

I would love to know if there are any other approached to this without a join but instead mapping the values as a new column to the table.

Thank you in advance for your time.
Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `col2` is unique in `sub_table`, you can use a subquery:

```
select m.*,
    (select s.col1 from sub_table s where s.col2 = m.col3) as col4
from main_table m
```

Or you can join:

```
select m.*, s.col1
from main_table m
inner join sub_table s on s.col2 = m.col3
```

It is unclear what you mean by *insert* in your question. If you want to update `col4` in existing rows of `main_table`, you can do:

```
update main_table m
set col4 = (select s.col1 from sub_table s where s.col2 = m.col3)
```

Comment: The first query worked perfectly well. I mentioned INSERT as i created a an empty column and then wanted to populate it but then, i realized that it was not the approach. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: I wanted to achieve this without a join! subquery was what i was looking for. Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
select m.*, s.col1 as col4 
from main_table m
left join sub_table s
on s.col2 = m.col3
```

if applied to sample data from your question - output is

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

select m.*, s.col1 as col4 from sub_table s,main_table m where s.col2 = m.col3